# Spring batch. How to chain multiple itemProcessors with different types?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

i have to compose 2 processors as following :

- `processor 1` implement the `itemProcessor` Interface with  `itemProcessor<A,B>` (transforming data).
- `processor 2` implement the `itemProcessor` Interface with  `itemProcessor<B,B>`.(treat transformed data).

the `CompositeItemProcessor<I, O>` requires the delegates to be in the same type , moreover when passing it to the `Step`  the step is already configure with fixed types `<A,B>`.

how i could chain these processors with different types and assign it to the `step` processor ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to declare your step as well as your composite processor with `<A, B>`. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<A> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(new A("a1"), new A("a2")));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<A, B> itemProcessor1() {
        return item -> new B(item.name);
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<B, B> itemProcessor2() {
        return item -> item; // TODO process item as needed
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<A, B> compositeItemProcessor() {
        CompositeItemProcessor<A, B> compositeItemProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
        compositeItemProcessor.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(itemProcessor1(), itemProcessor2()));
        return compositeItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<B> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (B item : items) {
                System.out.println("item = " + item.name);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<A, B>chunk(2)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .processor(compositeItemProcessor())
                        .writer(itemWriter())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
    
    class A {
        String name;
        public A(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }

    class B {
        String name;
        public B(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , however it doesn't solve the problem , i have seen the source code of the compositeItemProcessor it is a generic type <I,O> , in the process method it expects the delegates itemProcessors to be in the same type <I,O> .declared with, which is not my case i have itemProcessors with different  types

Comment: You asked for how to use an `ItemProcessor<A, B>` and an `ItemProcessor<B, B>` in a composite and this is exactly what the example shows. Where do you see the composite requiring the delegates to have the same type? Here is the code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/a7092a21e428cf904f210aff2682b518dc3649c5/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.java#L39, the composite is of type `<I, O>` and the delegates are of type `<?, ?>`.

Comment: As long as the composite's types are the same as what the step is expecting, it does not matter how many delegate processors you have in between: If the step reads items of type `A` and writes items of type `D` (like `.<A, D>chunk(5)` for example), you can have processors `A->B`, `B->C` and `C->D` as delegates of a `CompositeItemProcessor<A, D>`, as long as the output type of one processor is the same as the input type of the next processor in the chain.

Comment: Thanks Mr Mahmoud i was having a problem in another part sorry, this has solved the problem

Comment: Hi, I'm facing with a similar situation and I'm trying a couple of days to find a solution. Is it possible or what's the correct approach when: Read XML -> ComplexObject -> List<Model> -> Model -> Write. Is it possible to do that with ItemProcessors?